# List not displaying correctly WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

**Situation**

Hey guys, for a program I'm developing I have a *getRaces()* method:

```
public string getAllBaseRaces()
        {
            //string to hold a list of members
            string strRaces = "";


            foreach (BaseRace s in races)
            {
                strRaces = strRaces + s.ToString() + "\n";
            }


            return strRaces;
        }
```

I'm trying to populate a list with my *getRaces(*) methods return, which is a string, but when I do that I get something that looks like this:

```
this.DataContext = hillracing.getAllBaseRaces();
```

*https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifEtU.jpg*

The contents of the listbox are correct, it displays all of my parameters, like the name of the race, the ID of the Race, the Type of the race, it also shows all races as it's meant too, that part is fine.

**Problem**

It seems as if when the string is displaying, it's displaying incorrectly, as it's storing *each character* as a separate list item, rather than *each Race* being Seperate list item.

I've looked online and solutions are vague and don't really fit my scenario specifically.

**However**

when I *just* show the List in my Hillracing class (Which Stores Race Objects) I get something like this:

```
this.DataContext = hillracing.Races;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xmtt5.jpg

--Obviously, the second example image is the better of the two, and it's what I'm trying to achieve with the getRaces() method but I've failed at doing so, so I'm temporarily using this so I can work around it, the reason I can't use this as a permanent solution is because I don't have a list for All Member types, just BaseMember and I don't have a List for all Races, just BaseRace.

In short, With getRaces() as it is currently, It's not incredibly helpful since it's output is strange, I wondered how I could achieve the second image by using the getRaces() method.

**XAML for list**

```
<Grid Background="#19535353" Margin="-5,-3,-4,-4">
                    <Button Content="Create a Race" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="56,163,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" Height="110"/>
                    <Button x:Name="getRacesButton" Content="Get All Races" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="56,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" Height="110" Click="getRacesButton_Click_1"/>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding hillracing}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="326,273,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="406" Margin="287,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="335" ItemsSource="{Binding hillracing}"/>
                    <Button Content="Join Selected Race" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="287,441,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" Height="42"/>
                    <Button Content="Edit Selected Race" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="469,441,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="153" Height="42" RenderTransformOrigin="0.34,0.548"/>
                </Grid>
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: You need to provide us with more code

Comment: There really is no more code to give though, my method works, it's just the output that doesn't.

The output of the method works well in a TextBox, but not very well in a List.

Comment: Can you show me your xaml

Comment: @Method Please note that "hi something does not work the way I expect it to, using my code that I will not show in this question. Tell me what is wrong". is not how Stack Overflow works. Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and more specifically [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then [edit] your question to add details. Or in case, as you say "my method works" just delete this question.

Comment: I added the method to my question, but it really has nothing to do with this question.

The question is how to adjust output

Comment: your problem is on "\n", i suggest you debug your code nd watch is the output as expected

Comment: Actually your problem is the `DataContext` turning the string into an `IEnumerable` of `char`. If you want a list of strings in the listbox, don't concatenate them, return an array `string[]` (or `List<string>`) of all the items you want to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding to `ItemsSource` on `ListBox`.  This expects *multiple* items, but you are binding a single `string`.

`string` can be treated as an `IEnumerable<char>`, so an item is generated for each character in that `string`.  This is why you're seeing one character per line.

You should be binding to a more useful `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` represents each item.  If you wanted to stick with string, something like:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetRaces()
{
    foreach (BaseRace race in races)
    {
        yield return race.ToString();
    }
}
```

That said, I don't see what you're trying to do with this method.  Why not just bind to `Races` instead (like your second example)?

Comment: it defeats the purpose of even having a GetRaces If I can just use the List.

It just defeats the purpose of my code, but it DOES work.

Comment: @Method yes, it does, but you haven't provided a compelling reason why `GetRaces` is needed.  Don't add code just for the sake of it!

Comment: You're correct, alas, I'm in an OOP class, and I had to make a class Diagram with these methods, they are required to be designed, so I might as well use them.

If I don't use them, then there's TRULY no point in them being there.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation on this Charles, I didn't know why it was just displaying chars.

Comment: MVVM is often used with WPF - the XAML *binds* to various properties and commands on the *ViewModel*.  Using this paradigm, your *Get Races* button would be bound to a *command* and this would update an `ObservableCollection` property called `Races` which is bound to your list box.  Something to consider looking at if you stick with WPF past the class. Good luck!